# c# outlook add-in convert msg to eml

Tags: c#, outlook, eml

Is there any way to read a mail within outlook (using an add-in) and save it as an EML file?

Answer (score 3):

You can go two ways to achieve your goal:

1. You can do it **programmatically**.
   Try to use a third-party library [Aspose.Email for .Net](https://products.aspose.com/email/net?utm_source=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594445/c-sharp-outlook-add-in-convert-msg-to-eml&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=c-sharp-outlook-add-in-convert-msg-to-eml).
   This is a great library, which can be used for basic email management features. In this case, we will use a converting.
   Furthermore, this library is able to manipulate and edit messages, send and receive emails via several protocols and work with message storage files.

With the following code, you can easily convert MSG to EML. Look how simple it is with [Aspose.Email for .NET](https://products.aspose.com/email/net?utm_source=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594445/c-sharp-outlook-add-in-convert-msg-to-eml&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=c-sharp-outlook-add-in-convert-msg-to-eml).

```
using (var message = Aspose.Email.MailMessage.Load("template.msg»))
{  
    message.Save("output.eml", Aspose.Email.SaveOptions.DefaultEml); 
}
```

2. Use **online converters**.
   If you don’t want to do it programmatically, you can do it with online converters. You can use [Aspose.Email Conversion](https://products.aspose.app/email/conversion?utm_source=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594445/c-sharp-outlook-add-in-convert-msg-to-eml&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=c-sharp-outlook-add-in-convert-msg-to-eml).
   This is a free online converter, which provides you with converting from MSG to a bunch of different file formats. It has a friendly user-interface.

I am a Developer Evangelist at Aspose.

Answer (score 0):

You can either

1 - Create MIME file explicitly in your code one property at a time. You can also use existing MIME converters (I used Lumisoft in the past) - but they won't convert Outlook messages in a single call; you will need to explicitly build all the headers and MIME parts.

2 - Use [IConverterSession](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa192944(v=office.11).aspx) object (C++ or Delphi only) - this is the MIME converter used by Outlook when sending messages through SMTP. You can play with it in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its auithor) - click IConverterSession button.

3 - Use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) and its [RDOMail](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm).`SaveAs` or [SafeMailItem](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/SafeItem.htm).`SaveAs` methods - it can save in the MIME format (olRfc822) along with a dozen or so other formats. It uses [IConverterSession](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa192944(v=office.11).aspx) object when it is available (Outlook 2003 and up) or its own converter for an older version of Outlook or when used against the Exchange version of MAPI.
The following script (VBS) will save the currently selected message in Outlook as an EML file

```
  set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
  Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
  set rItem = Session.GetMessageFromID(Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1).EntryID)
  rItem.SaveAs "c:\temp\test.eml", 1024`
```